# Why python compile not works if nested class definitions exists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree

I trying to compile valid python code but there is not success - program work in python but can not be compiled to ast. I do not know why it happen - I checked space\tabs but I think that is not what is important.

```
class NdbModelForm(unittest.TestCase):
  def testLoadPostStringProperty(self):
    class DeleteMe(ndb.Model):
      name = ndb.StringProperty()
    pass
```

Code is not too complex but when I want parse this code I get such invalid exception:

```
    codeTree = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mroObject))
  File "C:\root\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    class DeleteMe(ndb.Model):
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

What to do to fix this code or workaround problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that answer is easy:

```
codeTree = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mroObject))
```

Should be replaced by:

```
codeTree = ast.parse(textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(mroObject)))
```

Looks simple but hard to find such explanation.